# electron Read and Write to usb drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

im working on electron project.
the project needs to copy files from the pc into usb drives.
i need to be able to copy files and folders to the destenetion usb drive.
and to know the amount of free space on the drive.

i tried difrrents npms like [usb npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb)
and im getting this error:

```
C:\Users\goorlavi1\Documents\pc-transfer>npm install --save usb

> usb@1.2.0 install C:\Users\goorlavi1\Documents\pc-transfer\node_modules\usb
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://github.com/tessel/node-usb/releases/download/1.2.0/usb_bindings-v1.2.0-node-v51-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for usb@1.2.0 and node@7.2.1 (node-v51 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

its too long to past here...

if its possible to provide example code its will be great Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

All this means (generally) is that there is some C++ module that hasn't yet been compiled against your machine. Node-pre-gyp will try to compile the C++ into Node. However, you need a C++ compiler on your machine for it to do this. For example, if you are running on a mac, it will likely just run on gcc/g++, if you are on a linux box, you will have to install gcc/g++, and if your are on windows you will have to find an alternative compiler.

I assume you are running from windows, and I apologize, because I haven't yet had cause to find a good C++ compiler for windows that works with pre-gyp, but I don't think you should have much of a problem finding one.